# Change HDMI color space using X11 API

Tags: c++, c, nvidia, x11

The nvidia settings tools offers the possibility to change the HDMI color space to `RGB` or `YCbCr444` as shown in this picture
[image]

I wonder if there is a way to do the same using X11 API (aka, modifying the color space of the HDMI output/screen) ?

Comment: What do you mean by the same ? 1. Modifying the ColorSpace of the screen ? 2. Modifying the ColorSpace of the XClient Window ? Could provide some answer in both case.

Comment: I would like to modify the color space of the screen

Answer (score 0):

**Modifying your Screen Colorspace**

**1. Programmaticaly**

`xlib` doesn't provide a way to modify the Colorspace screen hardware.
So, you have to use your vendor specific API, if it exists.
Luckily, `nvidia` provides an API clearly named `nvapi`.
It was designed for MSWIN, but since some years ago, it is available on Linux too:

[nvapi-open-source-sdk](http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvapi-open-source-sdk/)

NVidia provides a programmer's guide (a bit outdated) too:

[PG-5116-001_v02_public.pdf](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/tools/docs/PG-5116-001_v02_public.pdf)

which is more explicit than the one you'll get from the sdk.

**2. or Manually at startup**

**2.1 using xorg.conf config options**

- according to `xconfigoptions` from the nvidia documentation (see your nvidia package),

> they may be specified either in the Screen or Device sections of the X config file

So you could have something like:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
# ...
    Option "ColorSpace" "YCbCr444"
# ...
EndSection
```

**2.2 Using `nvidia-settings` tool:**

You can query your current settings:

`$ nvidia-settings --query=CurrentColorSpace`

from which you will retrieve the display number and its value
then, you could modify it from shell script (eg .xinitrc) or from command line:

`$ nvidia-settings --assign=:0[dpy:2]/ColorSpace=0`

where `:0` is your X11 `$DISPLAY`, and `dpy:2` the screen you want to modify